# Firebase Send a Notification to a User Segment on iOS not working

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, push-notification, firebase-notifications

I've installed according to the [manual](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/).

But only when I send the message to all iOS platform, only then **I am getting the push notification**. But when I am sending my massage to [specific version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/ios/console-audience) or [specific device](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/ios/console-device) for testing purposes, the massage is not received on the device. 
[image]
[image]
**What could be the problem?**

The strange thing, is when I ran the application with a new version, I do not see this version in the versions dropdown for couple of days. Even though that the code does reach

```
FIRApp.configure()
```

[image]

- ran the code with 2.5.5 version

Comment: In the case of sending to a specific device could you add how you are retrieving the token, in some cases you can have more than one token which invalidates previous ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a pod :-/

Instead of

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

I had:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
```

Strangely, before the change, the project compiled and instanceID was generating, even though the pushes were not received to the device. Adding the missing pod fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you get the right token ?

The token can be obtained by FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!

But The registration token may change when,

The app deletes Instance ID.

The app is restored on a new device.

The user uninstalls/reinstall the app.

The user clears app data.

Double check your token and make sure you enter right token.